# Error al devolver un array en java

Tags: java, array, método

Tengo un programa que tiene un método que rellena un array aleatorio entre 1-9  y luego en el programa principal me lo debe mostrar. El problema es que al mostrarlo me muestra letras y caracteres raros, no sé si lo he programado mal o tengo algún problema en eclipse...Me muestra lo siguiente "[I@15db9742" .

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class mistermind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(crear_tabla());
    }
    public static int[] crear_tabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[]=new int [5];
        for(int i=0;i>matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

        }
        return matrizDefecto;
    }

}
```

Comment: Estas imprimiento la referencia en memoria del método `crear_tabla`

Comment: No estas llenando la matriz, por eso te muestra la dirección. el error esta en el for, nunca se ejecuta el for, no se cumple la condición i mayor que 5 porque i lo inicias en cero por lo tanto esta mal tu condición, lo correcto seria i<5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que usar el  metodo `toString`. Por cierto en el ejemplo que mostraste tienes ciclo que rellena el arreglo malo, es `i < matrizDefecto.length`

te dejo el código para que lo pruebes

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import Java.util.Arrays;

public class mistermind {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // crear_tabla retorna un array al que le aplicamos el metodo toString
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(crear_tabla()));
}
public static int[] crear_tabla() {
    int matrizDefecto[] = new int [5];
    // aquí tenías el error 
    for(int i = 0; i < matrizDefecto.length; i++) {
        matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

    }
    return matrizDefecto;
}
```

Comment: No, me sigue mostrando la dirección porque me muestra esto "[I@6d06d69c".

Comment: si usaste el `toString` ? como te mencionaron, al imprimir un array directamente esto te mostrara la referencia en memoria, para imprimir el contenido como texto debes usar el método `toString`

Comment: si,hice un copy paste de tu post.

Comment: perdon el tostring de los array se usa diferente ahora te hago el cambio

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es imprimir el contenido de tu matriz prueba con esto:

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class mistermind {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 //Declaramos una nueva matriz donde metemos el valor que retorna tu metodo
 int matrizRecuperada[]=crear_tabla();

 //Recorremos toda la longitud de la matriz
 for(int x=0; x<matrizRecuperada.length; x++){

     //Accedemos al indice de la matriz para imprimir el valor que contiene 
     System.out.println(matrizRecuperada[x]);
 }

}
public static int[] crear_tabla() {
int matrizDefecto[]=new int [5];
for(int i=0;i>matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
    matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

}
return matrizDefecto;
  }
}
```

Como te comente antes lo que estabas haciendo era imprimir la referencia en memoria de tu método por eso te imprimía ese valor.

Comment: Me da como resultado todo 0 no recupera la  matrizDefecto.

Comment: No pude probar el codigo, pero la idea esta ahi, dame un segundo.

Comment: El problema esta en el for `for(int i=0;i>matrizDefecto.length;i++) {` tiene que ser `i<matrizDefecto.length`

Comment: @JDev Gracias, bien visto :) , no pude probar el código.

Comment: Ahora si porfin gracias! Ahora si no os importa una duda teórica, porque al mostrar return matrizDefecto me muestra la referencia de la memoria y no retorna el array en sí? Es decir, si quiero retornar un array que esta dentro de un método siempre tendré que en el main crear un array auxiliar para poder mostrar el original?

Comment: Puesto que para acceder al valor tienes que indicar el objeto -> `matrizDefecto[posicion que desees acceder]` y si imprimes únicamente `matrizDefecto`  estas imprimiendo el OBJETO en si,lo que te retorna su referencia.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @HectorLopez de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Aporto con otra forma, y es hacer la matriz sin tipo y presentar el contenido mientras se llena.

```
public class mistermind{

     public static void main(String []args){
        crear_tabla();
     }

     public static void crear_tabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[]=new int [5];
        for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);
            System.out.print(matrizDefecto[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Como dice LPZadkiel en su aportación, el operador en el lazo for debe ser menor: <